# How to debug React import/export errors in Meteor

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am refactoring a large Meteor project with considerable React code. After moving code around, I get this error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at invariant (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:13823:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.instantiateReactComponent [as _instantiateReactComponent] (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:28480:56)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:28908:22)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:28799:21)
    at Object.mountComponent (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:21654:35)
    at Object.obj.(anonymous function) [as mountComponent] (chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/backend.js:8598:20)
    at mountComponentIntoNode (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:33765:32)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:22605:20)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:33787:15)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=97484ff32aea5009d2055c2b506696595ed18f39:22605:20)
```

Now I am sure this is due to a missing export/ bad import statement.
But the question is .. where? Nothing in the console log is helpful in figuring out where I need to look. All the links point to framework code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know it's about import/exports? Isn't it about wrong proptypes?

Comment: Even if so - I was hoping to see an error which points to a line number in the source!